Zero voltage difference between two connected circuits
Here is my diagram:

Let us call circuit on the left A and circuit on right B. As you can see, there is no voltage difference between them (voltmeter). This is puzzling to me. One circuit has current of 1A and another has current 10A. It means that if freeze a moment of time and count charges at particular slice of circuit A and similar slice of circuit B, then circuit B will have 10 more times charges than circuit A. Therefore, there should be voltage difference. What am I missing?

Kirchoff's current law tells us that the sum of currents flowing into and out of a node must be zero. That implies that current can only flow in loops. Where is the loop that goes through R3? How is it possible for total current into and out of either of the nodes connecting to R3 to be zero if the current through R3 is not zero?


One circuit has current of 1A and another has current 10A. It means that if freeze a moment of time and count charges at particular slice of circuit A and similar slice of circuit B, then circuit B will have 10 more times charges than circuit A.

Current doesn't tell you how many charges, it tells you how many charges pass a given point in a certain amount of time. Imagine two highways, and on both highways, ten cars drive by in every minute. There's more than one way for that to be true. For example;

Could be that cars on both highways are moving at the same speed, but the one highway has ten times as many cars per kilometer as the other (i.e., more cars) OR,
Could be that there's the same number of cars per kilometer on both highways, but the cars on the one highway are moving ten times as fast.

Case (2) is a better analogy for current. The number of current carriers (valence electrons) per unit distance is baked into the atomic-scale structure of the conductors. If there's more current—more electrons passing a given point in each second—it's because the drift velocity of the electrons is greater.

Current flows in loops. That's why we call these things "circuits".

The way you have drawn it is the problem. The entire right half of the circuit is "floating" with respect to ground. No current can flow through R3 because the entire right side of the circuit is isolated, and if an electron went into the right side of the circuit through R3 it would have to come out somewhere. Therefore if no current is flowing through R3, the voltage across it is zero! V=IR. So it makes sense that you are measuring 0V across R3.

One circuit has current of 1A and another has current 10A. It means that if freeze a moment of time and count charges at particular slice of circuit A and similar slice of circuit B, then circuit B will have 10 more times charges than circuit A.

This is not true. The metal wire has a certain number of free electrons per cubic milimeter that is fixed. Having 1A vs 10A flowing through the wire just means the electrons are flowing 10x faster in the 10A case, not that there are more electrons per cubic milimeter.

So if I add ground to the right side, things will change?

If you add a ground to the right side of R3, things won't really change because you have the left side connected to ground (0V) and the right side connected to ground (0V) so again no current will flow through R3.

@user1700890, If you add ground to the right side, then that will be a different circuit. But also, it will be a circuit in which both sides of R3 are connected to the same circuit node. In that case, the voltage across R3 can be trivially shown to be zero, and the current through it must again be zero.

I think your confusion arises because you are assuming here that charge difference leads to potential difference as your last sentence "...then circuit B will have 10 more times charges than circuit A. Therefore, there should be voltage difference..." causes me to think that.
First of all, current, $I=\frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta t}$. Meaning, the more the current, the more charges passes through a part of the circuit in a unit time. If you take a snapshot of an instant, you will indeed see more charges in a slice of the right circuit that you mentioned. But, this, the number of charges you see in the snapshot, has nothing to do with potential at different parts of the circuit. Look at this example diagram:

If that is the confusion look at this circuit. The currents in the two simple circuits are 10A and 100A. So if you freeze at any instant, you will count more charges in the right circuit which is connected to 100V. But look, both of them are connected to ground and this makes the potential difference across the bottom resistor zero and no current flows through it. Indeed more charges will go through B than through A but both are at the same potential V=0.
Similarly the circuit you mentioned is set up in such a way that the potential difference between P and Q is zero.

Hope if that is the confusion, it is cleared. Both the circuits, left and right can be treated independently as if they are not connected.

Thank you for response. But I do think " charge difference leads to potential difference ".

@user1700890 Could you explain why do you think so? so that I can get more insight to your question?


…then circuit B will have 10 more times charges than circuit A.
Therefore, there should be voltage difference. What am I missing?

It’s the rate of charge transport per unit time through a surface, which is the definition of current, in circuit B that’s 10 times greater than circuit A, not the amount of charge at a given time. In any event, the difference in current between the circuits has nothing to do with the potential difference across R3.
Kirchhoff’s voltage law tells us the potential difference across R3 must be zero. Assuming ideal voltmeters (infinite resistance), ammeters (zero resistance) and voltage sources (zero internal resistance) the current in the “loop” containing R3, V1 and the gap between R2 and R3 must be zero, and since no other loop carrying current includes R3, the potential difference across R3 must be zero.
Since the potential difference across R3 is zero, that means R3 can be replaced by a short circuit, i.e. replaced by a single node.
The total current (1A and 10A) into this node common to both circuits equals the total current going out of the node, satisfying Kirchhoff’s current law.
Hope this helps.
